# Linq equivalent

Tags: linq, .net-3.5

```
foreach (ParameterGroup paramGroup in ParamGroups)
        {
            foreach (Parameter parameter in paramGroup.ParameterList)
            {
                if (parameter.ParameterId == parameterId)
                    return paramGroup.GroupId;
            }
        }
```

What would be LINQ eqiavalent?

Comment: What happens at the moment if there's no match?

Comment: @AakashM 0 is returned. I've changed Albin Sunnanbo's code a little so that Default value was set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (from paramGroup in ParamGroups
        from parameter in paramGroup.ParameterList
        where parameter.ParameterId == parameterId
        select paramGroup.GroupId).FirstOrDefault();
```